# Incremento de un atributo

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Tengo el siguiente código el cuál debe incrementar el valor del atributo en 1, teniendo en cuenta las siguientes condiciones:

Si el valor de los minutos es igual a 59 antes del incremento, entonces, si el valor de las horas es menos de 23, el método incrementará en 1 horas y pondrá a cero el valor de minutos, pero, si por el contrario, el valor de horas es igual a 23, siendo los minutos igual a 59, el método pondrá a cero ambos atributos
**Me falla en uno de esos "test"**

```
class Time:
    """Clase que muestra el tiempo"""
    def __init__(self, h, m):
        """Time objects are initialized with hours and minutes"""
        self.horas = h
        self.minutos = m

    def tiempo_incrementacion(self):
        if self.minutos == 59 or self.horas == 23:
            if self.horas < 23:
                self.horas += 1
                self.minutos = 0
            elif self.minutos == 59:
                self.horas = 0
                self.minutos = 0

t = Time(12, 30)
print("Horas = {} y minutos = {}".format(t.horas, t.minutos)) # Prints "Horas = 12 y minutos = 30"
t.increase()
print("Horas = {} y minutos = {}".format(t.horas, t.minutos)) # Prints "Horas = 12 y minutos = 31"

t = Time(12, 59)
print("Horas = {} y minutos = {}".format(t.horas, t.minutos)) # Prints "Horas = 12 y minutos = 59"
t.increase()
print("Horas = {} y minutos = {}".format(t.horas, t.minutos)) # Prints "Horas = 13 y minutos = 0"

t = Time(23, 59)
print("Horas = {} y minutos = {}".format(t.horas, t.minutos)) # Prints "Horas = 23 y minutos = 59"
t.increase()
print("Horas = {} y minutos = {}".format(t.horas, t.minutos)) # Prints "Horas = 0 y minutos = 0"
```

Comment: No usaría la palabra Time para declarar una clase podría prestar a.confusion , por otro lado por que no haces el incremento en la misma librería time y que el maneje el tiempo para eso se creó estás reinventando la rueda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira

Solo le cambie si los minutos son 59 entonces minutos = 0 y vamos a comprobar si la hora es 23 y si es 23 se cambia a 0 sino se le suma 1 y si los minutos no son 59 se le suma 1

```
class Time:
    """Clase que muestra el tiempo"""
    def __init__(self, h, m):
        """Time objects are initialized with hours and minutes"""
        self.horas = h
        self.minutos = m

    def increase(self):
        if self.minutos == 59:
           self.minutos = 0

           self.horas = 0 if self.horas == 23 else self.horas + 1  
        else:
          self.minutos += 1



t = Time(12, 30)
print("Horas = {} y minutos = {}".format(t.horas, t.minutos)) # Prints "Horas = 12 y minutos = 30"
t.increase()
print("Horas = {} y minutos = {}".format(t.horas, t.minutos)) # Prints "Horas = 12 y minutos = 31"

t = Time(12, 59)
print("Horas = {} y minutos = {}".format(t.horas, t.minutos)) # Prints "Horas = 12 y minutos = 59"
t.increase()
print("Horas = {} y minutos = {}".format(t.horas, t.minutos)) # Prints "Horas = 13 y minutos = 0"

t = Time(23, 59)
print("Horas = {} y minutos = {}".format(t.horas, t.minutos)) # Prints "Horas = 23 y minutos = 59"
t.increase()
print("Horas = {} y minutos = {}".format(t.horas, t.minutos)) # Prints "Horas = 0 y minutos = 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizás la recomendación para este tipo de casos sería usar el operador `%` con el fin de evitar el anidamiento de los condicionales `if... else`.

Dicho operador `%` es útil porque permite definir ciclos como el reloj mediante la división del número que aumenta o disminuye (numerador) y el límite del ciclo (denominador), así por ejemplo se tiene en el caso de las horas

```
0 % 24 = 0
1 % 24 = 1
2 % 24 = 2
.
.
.
23 % 24 = 23
0 % 24 = 0 # Bingo! se reinicia el contador de horas

# testea con este pequeño código
# for i in range(30):
#     print("{} % 24 = {}".format(i,i%24))
```

Por tanto una posible implementación de la clase **"Cronometro"** quedaría de la siguiente forma (dicha clase incluye también el reporte -*mirarCronometro*- para no estar repitiendo código de impresión)

```
class Cronometro:
    def __init__(self, h, m):
        self.horas = h
        self.minutos = m


    def contarMinuto(self):
        self.minutos = ( self.minutos + 1 ) % 60

        if self.minutos == 0:
            self.horas = ( self.horas + 1 ) % 24

        self.mirarCronometro()


    def mirarCronometro(self):
        print("{}h: {}m".format(self.horas, self. minutos))


t = Cronometro(0,0)
t.mirarCronometro()


for i in range(1,1500):
    t.contarMinuto()
```